# Store and retreieve blob from sqllite database for android

Tags: android, database, eclipse, image, recording

I need to know to define blob data type in eclipse. I am developing an app for android and i want to save image and a recording in database. I know have to use blob as the data type. My question is how do i define it in the class and the DBhandler class. Can someone provide me help with codes.

Answer (score 6):

Blob is used to save byte array in sqlite.

To convert a bitmap to byte array use following code:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thumbnail);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

byte[] buffer=out.toByteArray();
```

To save a byte array in blob type use following code:

```
   ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
   cv.put(CHUNK, buffer);       //CHUNK blob type field of your table
   long rawId=database.insert(TABLE, null, cv); //TABLE table name
```

Read more about Blob by this [link](http://lunarmonk.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/android-sqlite-story-of-a-blob/)