# How to save Map screenshot into database in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, screenshot

I am trying to make an app  which will on a single button click will take a screenshot of the map and then save it to the SQLLite database altogether.
Can anyone help with how to do so...thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

Taking ScreenShot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/547995

Store in SQLite as Blob: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11790199/547995

Comment: Just so you know, I believe this violates the terms of use for google maps.  https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en see 10.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Google Map Provides map snapshot option

```
mRouteMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {

        }
    });
```