# How to save bitmap from ImageView to database sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, android-studio

I am trying save a Bitmat from a ImageView on database sqlite but I can't do.

I save Strings but I dont know Images.

My code

**BBDD class**

```
public class BBDD extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    String create = "CREATE TABLE info(usuario TEXT, " +
                                        "ma TEXT, " +
                                        "ti TEXT, " +
                                        "loc TEXT, " +
                                        "lati TEXT, " +
                                        "longi TEXT, " +
                                        "obs TEXT," +
                                        "date TEXT, " +
                                        "time TEXT, " +
                                        "in TEXT, " +
                                        "imgone BLOB, " +
                                        "imgtwo BLOB, " +
                                        "imgthree BLOB, " +
                                        "imgfour BLOB) ";

    public BBDD (Context contexto, String nombre, CursorFactory factory,
                 int version)
    {
        super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(create);
    }

    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnt, int versionNue)
    {
        db.execSQL(create);
    }
}
```

**activity**

```
//******//

//declares
public BBDD info;

//******//

//onClick button to save 
 public void send (View view)
    {
        usuario = "ful";
        ma = tv_ma.getText().toString();
        ti = "T";
        loc = tv_lug.getText().toString();
        lati = tv_latib.getText().toString();
        longi = tv_longb.getText().toString();
        obs = txtStatus.getText().toString();

        SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String data="";
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        data=dfDate.format(c.getTime());
        date = data;

        SimpleDateFormat dfDate2  = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String data2="";
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        data2=dfDate2.format(c2.getTime());
        time = data2;

        in = tv_infraccionb.getText().toString();

        info = new BBDD(this, "BBDD", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = info.getWritableDatabase();

//*****//
//validate empty variables
//*****//

if (db != null) {

            ContentValues reg = new ContentValues();

            reg.put("usuario", usuario);
            reg.put("ma", ma);
            reg.put("ti", ti);
            reg.put("loc", loc);
            reg.put("lati", lati);
            reg.put("longi", longi);
            reg.put("obs", obs);
            reg.put("date", date);
            reg.put("time", time);
            reg.put("in", in);
```

**My problem here, I dont know how I can save Images on "reg.put..."**

```
            if (db.insert("info", null, reg) != -1) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Reg insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                db.close();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

**I get the image of bundle Bitmap format**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        byte[] food = extras.getByteArray("picture");
        Bitmap fo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(food, 0, food.length);

        img_ImageView.setImageBitmap(fo);
```

any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

**SOLUTION**

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        img = bos.toByteArray();
        db=info.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("image", img);     
        db.insert("info",null, cv);
```

Comment: you can try from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert Bitmap-->Byte array and then insert Byte array into DB,

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.kitkat);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] img = bos.toByteArray();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("image", img);
SQLiteDatabase database = null;
try {
        database = dbHelper.opendatabase();
            database.insert("android_version", null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
```

Comment: There are further examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android