# Storing and retrieve photo albums stored in different folders in raw resource by using URL in sqlite database

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android application which should first store paths of images which are kept in different folders in raw resource folder using sqlite database. Then I should be able to retrieve the stored images from the database using the stored paths. Kindly help.

Comment: try this, same problem here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: There image is stored using blob but i want to store all the different images using path and then retrieve using the same.

Comment: You can use lazy image loader to retrieve the images for listview it would be more effiecient let me inform if you have further queries

Comment: Mate I have to do it using an sqlite database only and I am not allowed to use blob.