# Storing image name in sqlite and picking image from drawable folder

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a list view in my app which consists of:

1. ImageView
2. TextView
3. Button

I want that when the user clicks on that button `textview` gets stored in database along with the name of the image which is stored in `drawable` folder. Now on another activity i need to show the listview which consists of only the items selected by the user. I don't know how to store image in database and retrieve it. Please help!

I have seen many questions on Stackoverflow but none is solving my problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.[How to store(bitmap image) and retrieve image from sqlite database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android)
.Also you should not store raw images in sqlite tables .Instead store their path to the directory.Hope it helps.

Comment: This is for storing the image itself in the sqlite. I don't want that...I want name to be stored See question again. If you could help please!

Comment: You may retrieve the id of the imageview by -v.getId();-Just store this Id in the database and as for the textVIew ,You may use -String str=tv.getText().toString(); - and store it in the database.For populating listview use the image id and text from the database.Hope it helps.