# Custom Listview using import SQLite for Retrieve Images and text on the same list

Tags: android

I’m newbie here, and now I’m develop some app,
I’m confuse about how to retrieve image and text in custom Listview and clickable like this Custom Listview Text and Image and Clickable
My question is, How to build Custom Listview like that and clickable every list into other activity? Please someone help me and ill appreciate for your hard work :) and i already have some db and I want to import and uses on android studio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No need for activity for every click see this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: @ArpitPatel hi arpit thanks for answer, if i want using offline database , what is best? SQLite or JSON? because i have like an hundred images with some names

Comment: see my answer and if it is useful then appreciate with vote :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raj
What is use for JSON and SQLite.

**JSON**  When you are getting data from server you need to use json.

**SQLite** When you don't need server data so you can use SQLite

When you have a lots of data i would prefer JSON.

and use this link for getting data from server.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Yes, im prefer using SQLite because i dont need server and internet access :D, but how to implement SQLite on your link give it on me ? can you help me?

Comment: see another androidhive link with good explanation http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: And this link show store image in SQLite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: Actually im follow this site http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html but idk how to retrieve images could you help me for retrieve images?

Comment: are you store this image in SQLite??

Comment: see it's next post for the store and retrieve images http://www.javahelps.com/2016/04/import-database-with-images-in-android.html

Comment: yes i want to store all image on SQLite, or you have another ways to do that? because all i need is to shown an image with text in listview from offline database

Comment: Yes im follow that too, exactly how to convert spinner into listview?

Comment: ya you have to fatch all images name and set into you listview adapter

Comment: i have low rep cant give more votes, yeah , my problem is i cant retrieve images in the same list

Comment: see this link http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/09/hello-friends-today-i-am-going-to-share.html

Answer (score 0):

1. To store data into local db (sqlite), you need to do some implementation, here's an effective guide of it:
   [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
2. Put your images into drawables , store their Resource Ids into database and get them in Listview's Custom Adapter
3. For Images async loading, try Lazy List or Lazy Adapter so that you can have a smooth scrolling for list. For it, use the above URL mentioned by @Dixit

Comment: my problem is i have hundred images and size more than 1mb,

Comment: @Raj No problem you can have drawables for size greater than 1mb, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Actually im follow this site http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html but idk how to retrieve images could you help me for retrieve images?

Comment: You want to retrieve images from server or you are having images locally and want to retrieve them on the basis of your queries to the database?

Comment: You can put all your images into drawable and in sqlite db you can store their drawable resource ids (You can retrieve their resource ids as e.g. R.drawable.image1).