# Insert image and some text fields into SQLite database - Android

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, android-studio

I am new in Android developing and I am trying to insert data into SQLite database in Android. I have a problem find the solution, where can I see code, how to insert Image and Text into database. Do you know some articles/books or 
something else which they help me ?

I write some code with inserting only text, but I cannot insert both together.
After inserting, I want to retrieve text and image in detail activity.

Very thank you for help.

I can upload the code.

My DatabaseHelper:

```
 public class DatabaseHelpher extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="student";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String STUDENT_TABLE = "stureg";
    private static final String STU_TABLE = "create table "+STUDENT_TABLE +"(name TEXT,email TEXT primary key,roll TEXT,address TEXT,branch TEXT)";

    Context context;

    public DatabaseHelpher(final Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(STU_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STUDENT_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertIntoDB(String name,String email,String roll,String address,String branch){
        Log.d("insert", "before insert");

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("email", email);
        values.put("roll", roll);
         values.put("address", address);
        values.put("branch", branch);

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(STUDENT_TABLE, null, values);
        // 4. close
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.i("insert into DB", "After insert");



    }

    public List<DatabaseModel> getDataFromDB(){
        List<DatabaseModel> modelList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String query = "select * from "+STUDENT_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                DatabaseModel model = new DatabaseModel();
                model.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                model.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
                model.setRoll(cursor.getString(2));
                model.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
                model.setBranch(cursor.getString(4));

                modelList.add(model);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        Log.d("student data", modelList.toString());


        return modelList;
    }



    public void deleteARow(String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(STUDENT_TABLE, "email" + " = ?", new String[] { email });
        db.close();
    }
```

DatabaseModel:

```
public class DatabaseModel {
private String name;
private String roll;
private String address;
private String branch;
private String email;
private String image;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

public void setRoll(String roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getBranch() {
    return branch;
}

public void setBranch(String branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage (String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

DetailsActivity:

```
 public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelpher helpher;
    List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
    int position;
    TextView tvname,tvemail,tvroll,tvaddress,tvbranch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        // 5. get status value from bundle
         position = bundle.getInt("position");

        tvname =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        tvemail =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        tvroll =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.roll);
        tvaddress =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        tvbranch =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.branch);
        helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(this);
        dbList= new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();

        if(dbList.size()>0){
            String name= dbList.get(position).getName();
            String email=dbList.get(position).getEmail();
            String roll=dbList.get(position).getRoll();
            String address=dbList.get(position).getAddress();
            String branch=dbList.get(position).getBranch();
            tvname.setText(name);
            tvemail.setText(email);
            tvroll.setText(roll);
            tvaddress.setText(address);
            tvbranch.setText(branch);
        }

        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, dbList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_details, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etName,etRoll,etAddress,etBranch,etEmail;
Button btnSubmit,btngetdata,btndroptable;
DatabaseHelpher helpher;
List<DatabaseModel> dbList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    dbList= new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etRoll = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRoll);
    etAddress =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    etBranch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBranch);
    etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    btnSubmit  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btngetdata =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btngetdata);

    btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

           // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class));

        }
    });

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name=etName.getText().toString();
            String email=etEmail.getText().toString();
            String roll=etRoll.getText().toString();
            String address=etAddress.getText().toString();
            String branch=etBranch.getText().toString();

        if(name.equals("") || email.equals("") || roll.equals("") ||address.equals("")||branch.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please fill all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(MainActivity.this);
            helpher.insertIntoDB(name, email, roll, address, branch);
        }
            etName.setText("");
            etRoll.setText("");
            etAddress.setText("");
            etBranch.setText("");
            etEmail.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
    });
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```
 public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static   List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
        static  Context context;
        RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DatabaseModel> dbList ){
            this.dbList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
            this.context = context;
            this.dbList = dbList;

        }
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_row, null);


        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(dbList.get(position).getName());
        holder.email.setText(dbList.get(position).getEmail());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView name,email;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvname);
            email = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvemail);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class);

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("position",getAdapterPosition());
            intent.putExtras(extras);

            context.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(RecyclerAdapter.context, "you have clicked Row " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
  public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelpher helpher;
    List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(this);
        dbList= new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleview);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Layouts**

ActivityDetails:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Roll"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/branch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Branch"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

ActivityMain:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Email"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Branch"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etBranch"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Address"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etAddress"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Roll"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etRoll"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Name"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="uložit do databáze"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btngetdata"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Zobrazit seznam rumů"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

ActivitySecond:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

item_row:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"  >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvemail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Very Very thanks for help, I dont know how to resolve problem with insert image and text into one database, then store them in mobile and after click to row then app display image and texts.
PS: sorry for a lot of code, but I dont know what to do :(

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/

Comment: @DivyangPanchal Thanks, but how to connect together ? I cannot find some articles with code. I want DetailFlow with this.

Comment: Do you want to store image into the database or the path of this image?

Comment: Images are never suggested to save in database. It makes your database heavy. Instead of saving image, save path to image in database.

Comment: @ChintanSoni, totally agree with you.

Comment: @ChintanSoni Ok, I understand. Do you know of something where I can see the code, someone trying to save data and then display them in detail activity?

Comment: For that, you have to throw more lights on what you want to achieve. From where you want to display images ? Depending on that, you get different suggestions.

Comment: @ChintanSoni Images that are stored on the SD card. The path is stored in the database, then the image is displayed in detail activity.

Comment: Check here how to insert your image. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11790199/1503155

Answer (score 0):

You should save your images into a specific folder
and then insert the path of each image into the database.

Then, when you want to retrieve your image, query your database, 
and find your image using the stored path.

There's a very good example of how to display the image when you've got the path: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182060/5778152

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class DatabaseHelpher extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="student";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String STUDENT_TABLE = "stureg";
    private static final String STU_TABLE = "create table "+STUDENT_TABLE +"(name TEXT,email TEXT primary key,roll TEXT,address TEXT,branch TEXT,,image BLOB)";

    Context context;

    public DatabaseHelpher(final Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(STU_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STUDENT_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertIntoDB(String name,String email,String roll,String address,String branch,byte[]image_data){
        Log.d("insert", "before insert");

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("email", email);
        values.put("roll", roll);
         values.put("address", address);
        values.put("branch", branch);
        values.put("image", image_data);

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(STUDENT_TABLE, null, values);
        // 4. close
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.i("insert into DB", "After insert");



    }


    public List<DatabaseModel> getDataFromDB(){
        List<DatabaseModel> modelList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String query = "select * from "+STUDENT_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                DatabaseModel model = new DatabaseModel();
                model.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                model.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
                model.setRoll(cursor.getString(2));
                model.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
                model.setBranch(cursor.getString(4));
                model.setImage(cursor.getBlob(5));  //Add byte paramter in your DatabaseModel
                modelList.add(model);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        Log.d("student data", modelList.toString());


        return modelList;
    }



    public void deleteARow(String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(STUDENT_TABLE, "email" + " = ?", new String[] { email });
        db.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: I update question with my DatabaseHelper code. Where to added the image insert?

Comment: 1st add  image column in your table like image BLOB.Then convert your image to byte and in insertIntoDB funcntion add    values.put(image, image_byte);

Comment: private static final String STU_TABLE = "create table "+STUDENT_TABLE +"(name TEXT,email TEXT primary key,roll TEXT,address TEXT,branch TEXT,image BLOB)";

Comment: Thanks man. Do you have a lite time, to help me? I update question with all my code, do you know, where to added everything to display after click in row text and image ?