# Insert Image with description to database table

Tags: android

I am new  in android I want to upload image with description and data should be stored in database table.
public class Send_News extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
//  private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String selectedFilePath;
private String SERVER_URL = "";
ImageView ivAttachment,ntwrk;
Button bUpload;
TextView tvFileName,tvHeading;
ProgressDialog dialog;
String answer;

private String TAG = Send_News.class.getSimpleName();
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send__news);
    ivAttachment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
    ntwrk = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ntwrk1);
    bUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    tvFileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
    tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);
    ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.fullscreen_ad_unit_id));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
            // .addTestDevice("ca-app-pub-4514287475704546~4354128510")
            .build();

    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });
}

private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }

}

//Checking Internet Connectivity//




//Internet Connectivity//




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //checking internet connection
        checkConnection();

        //on attachment icon click

    }
    if(v== bUpload){

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Send_News.this,"","Uploading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Send_News.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

//Checking ntwrk
private void checkConnection() {
    if(isOnline()){


        showFileChooser();
        //  Toast.makeText(SendNews.this, "You are connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ntwrk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    }else{
        View  view=findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout);
        Snackbar.make(view, "No Internet Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setDuration(5000)
                .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview_dark_background)).show();
```

//            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.snack_text_action));

```
        // snackbar.show();
        //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are not connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ntwrk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvHeading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

//ntwrk connection
private boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("*/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
            Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

            if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

//android upload file to server
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Send_News.this);

                        // Setting Dialog Title
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Thanks For Uploading News...");

                        // Setting Dialog Message
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you want to upload more News");

                        // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_addfile);

                        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                                Intent intent= new Intent(Send_News.this,Send_News.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                                Intent intent= new Intent(Send_News.this,MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        // Showing Alert Message
                        alertDialog.show();

                        // tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);

                    }
                });


            }




            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Send_News.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Send_News.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Send_News.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

}
```

}

Filepath Class
class FilePath {
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

```
    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            }


            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
```

}

In this code, text data is not uploaded and image is uploaded but not in database table. I want to upload image and text data in database table. So please tell me how i will do simultaneously uploading text and image in database table

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android             And do some research before posting the question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store(bitmap image) and retrieve image from sqlite database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to achieve this task

1. **Storing in Local Database:**

   if you want to save images and their description locally in app, then use sqlite database or realm to do that. You can create table in database having column of image and description. You can save image in base64 or using other encoding methods. While retrieving from database, you need to decode image to display.
2. **Uploading Images to Cloud Server:**
   if you want to upload images to cloud server then, you must create database table on server and call API that you must write in web language to upload your images to server. You can store image in folder on server and save path of folder along with image name in image column of created database.