# Trouble in Implementing Camera Images Storage in SQLite Database on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-image

I have recently made an App which has a basic Intent which opens the default camera app on device. 
But I want to expand it's functionality which will enable it to store the captured image from camera to the SQLite Database. Along with displaying the images already stored in the database. Also I want to display the Date & Time of the image which is captured below the image, as well as Add a Comment box below the date/time of the image.

The code for the MainActivity is as follows:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Code for the Activity's Layout XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Open Camera"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity,  why not store the image meta, ie. the uri and the other details you want in the data base rather than actually compressing the image and storing it ?

Comment: No, I want to store the image itself in the database, along with it's metadata (only date and time) and add a comment box next to it.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: Can you please guide me here, I can't understand anything from this link.

Comment: you can save Base64 String of your image in your local DB